# Error al querer modificar un registro quitándole su imagen de producto [MySQL] [JAVA] [Java.Io.FileNotFoundException]

Tags: java, mysql

actualmente estoy creando un sistema CRUD, sin embargo cuando selecciono un registro con imagen y a este quiero actualizarlo quitándole la imagen, me genera un error de try-catch obligándome a introducir una URL para tener una imagen. intente usar sentencia condional if, donde en caso de que no encuentre una dirección url envié null a las columnas de Url e Imagen a la base de datos para así dejarlas vacías pero al parecer no funciono :(
las columnas de mi tabla de datos:

**Url** contienen la dirección url de la imagen y **Imagen** la foto en varible BLOB

```
Connection con = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream archivofoto;
    
            File nombre = new File(txtImagen.getText());
            archivofoto = new FileInputStream(nombre);
            con = GetConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE lista SET Codigo=?,Articulo=?,Descripcion=?,Area=?,Serie=?,Marca=?,Medida=?,Color=?,Url=?,Imagen=? WHERE Codigo=?");
            ps.setString(1, txtCodigo_Crud.getText());
            ps.setString(2, cbArticulo_Crud.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(3, txtDescripcion_Crud.getText());
            ps.setString(4, cbArea_Crud.getSelectedItem().toString());
            ps.setString(5, txtSerie_Crud.getText());
            ps.setString(6, txtMarca_Crud.getText());
            ps.setString(7, txtMedida_Crud.getText());
            ps.setString(8, txtColor_Crud.getText());
            if (txtImagen.getText().equals(" ")) {
                ps.setString(9, " ");
                ps.setBinaryStream(10, null);
            } else {
                ps.setString(9, txtImagen.getText());
                ps.setBinaryStream(10, archivofoto);
            }
            ps.setString(11, txtCodigo_Crud.getText());
    
            int res = ps.executeUpdate();
            if (res > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Modificado");
                limpiar();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Modificar");
                limpiar();
            }
            con.close();
            cargarTabla();
            contar();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Error en actualización"+e,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
```

la finalidad es que me permita quitar la imagen de mi registro y dejarla vacía al actualizar, pero solo me envía este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error:

```
Java.Io.FileNotFoundException
```

esto debido a que no envió ninguna dirección URL al actualizar mi registro pero ahora sin imagen

Espero alguien tengo alguna idea sobre como pueda solucionarlo, de igual manera muchas gracias :)

Comment: Para poder darte una solución correcta debes de agregar el printStackTrace de la excepción para ver la linea que provoca el error y facilitar una solución por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 0):

Analizando tu código la explicación que diste es incorrecta por eso la importancia del `printStackTrace` , según puedo analizar  el error proviene del la linea `archivofoto = new FileInputStream(nombre);` porque el `FileInputStream` lanza una excepción  si el archivo no existe porque debe cargarlo en memoria primero, utiliza un `if` y el método `exists()` para comprobar la existencia del archivo por ejemplo:

```
    FileInputStream fis;
    File f = new File("h"); // achivo no existente
    if (f.exists() && f.isFile()){
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

al final valida de el FileInputStream no este nulo para agregarlo en la base de datos o agregar una imagen generica para los productos sin imagen.